# How do I reference a form field in a Javascript equation?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have this JavaScript, which adds up a series of numbers and creates a total. Then from that series of numbers it finds the lowest one and subtracts it from the total. I want the user to be able to input a numeric value and have that number be part of the equation. First I'll give you my code and then I'll tell you what I've tried.

This is the script that does the addition and subtraction:

```
var prices = [];
function remove(arr,itm){
  var indx = arr.indexOf(itm);
  if (indx !== -1){
    arr.splice(indx,1);
  }
}

function calculateSectedDues(checkbox, amount) {
  if (checkbox.checked === true) {
    prices.push(amount);
  } else {
    remove(prices, amount);
  }
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0, len = prices.length; i < len; i++)
    total += prices[i];

  var min = prices.slice().sort(function(a,b){return a-b})[0];
  if(typeof min === 'undefined') min = 0;
  var withDiscount = total - min;
  var discountAmount = withDiscount - total;
  document.querySelector("#total").innerHTML = total;
  document.querySelector("#discount").innerHTML = discountAmount;
  document.querySelector("#newTotal").innerHTML = withDiscount;
  document.getElementById("FinalTotal").value = withDiscount;
}
```

This is the form field I created that I want to pull into the equation:

```
<input name="yellowtape" type="text" id="yellowtape" style="width:243px;">
```

I thought that by adding:

```
var withDiscount = total + yellowtape - min ;
```

It would work but I cant figure it out. I need to add whatever number they enter in the form field 'yellowtape' to var withDiscount.

Comment: Use `document.getElementById("yellowtape").value` rather then just `yellowtape`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yellowtape` is the DOM element. You need to take its value and make sure it's a number:

```
var yellowtape = parseFloat(document.getElementById('yellowtape').value);
var withDiscount = total + yellowtape - min ;
```

Comment: That works perfectly with one minor exception. It adds itself to that array of all the numbers and will subtract itself because it will consider it to be one of the smallest number in that array. I want it to be solo by itself, no exceptions, its going to add itself to whatever the total is. Another words yellowtape can also be min in this scenario but I dont want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

What you have will work if you store the input value first:

```
var yellowtape = document.getElementById('yellowtape').value;
var withDiscount = total + yellowtape - min ;
```